Recommended models of USB 4G/LTE sticks for OpenWRT support
I'm thinking of configuring an internet router using a 4G/LTE USB stick.
I've looked at:
https://openwrt.org/toh/views/toh_lte_modem_supported
But I either don't know the brands or the models have been discontinued, etc, plus I don't see detailed reviews.
Has anyone configured an internet router with the inbound connection being a 4G/LTE USB stick connected to a Linux PC? If so, what did you choose?
I would order it in Europe (so amazon.de, not amazon.com).

That table doesn't actually mention the modem type at all. It just lists complete units that "have a modem" but doesn't say what kind.
But most such modems are USB devices (even the M.2-shaped modems) that offer the same few generic interfaces and do not require any proprietary driver. Usually they offer a standard MBIM or QMI interface, sometimes traditional Hayes AT commands, but to an extent they all should automatically be "compatible" with an up-to-date OS. See for example:

https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/network/wan/wwan/ltedongle

There are some modems which need a special power-on sequence before they actually show up as a modem, but the 'usb_modeswitch' database of those is also part of "up-to-date OS".

https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/network/wan/wwan/usb-modeswitching

If you run generic Linux, then ModemManager will support configuring all types. I don't know what OpenWrt has, but it definitely supports MBIM and QMI at least.
Even the USB sticks that expose fake Ethernet via RNDIS will work too, although they're likely to be less reliable, and often the OS doesn't see them as "LTE modems" at all. (In particular, I have learned to avoid Huawei USB sticks like plague.)

https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/network/wan/wwan/ethernetoverusb_rndis
https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/network/wan/wwan/ethernetoverusb_ncm

Generally I believe internal M.2 cards have a much higher chance of working reliably and supporting MBIM/QMI, while many USB sticks aim for "plug in and a network shows up" and that leads to the somewhat less reliable "fake Ethernet" RNDIS mode.
No specific model recommendations (even aside from it being explicitly off-topic for this site, I don't actually have any).

Is there an non-offtopic site for this?
